# TYPO3: clear cache of a page when file metadata is changed

Tags: php, caching, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a custom plugin which shows files for download based on sys_category.

When an editor changes the meta data of a file, e.g. changes the title or category, the changes are only reflected in the frontend when the complete frontend cache is cleared.

I've tried to add this to page TSconfig:

```
[page|uid = 0]
TCEMAIN.clearCacheCmd = 17
[global]
```

But this doesn't work. Any other idea how to clear the cache, when a `sys_file_metadata` record is changed?

Comment: You need the procesaDatamap and more specifically the afterAllOperations. There, if you edit a table, it gives you the ability to do something after TYPO3 is done with everything. You can call then the function clearCache or something like that. Not really sure how it is called. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/FrontendsBackends/Index.html

Comment: Thx @AristeidisKaravas for your hint. I've found a solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Thx Aristeidis for the hint.

**ext_localconf.php**

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass']['my_extension_key'] =
    \Vendor\ExtKey\Hooks\DataHandler::class;
```

**Classes/Hooks/DataHandler.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\ExtKey\Hooks;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class DataHandler
{
    public function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations(
        $status,
        $table,
        $recordUid,
        array $fields,
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $parentObject
    ) {
        if ($table === 'sys_file_metadata') {
            // hardcoded list of page uids to clear
            $pageIdsToClear = [17];

            if (!is_array($pageIdsToClear)) {
                $pageIdsToClear = [(int)$pageIdsToClear];
            }
            $tags = array_map(function ($item) {
                return 'pageId_' . $item;
            }, $pageIdsToClear);
            GeneralUtility::makeInstance(CacheManager::class)->flushCachesInGroupByTags('pages', $tags);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this could be improved more:

- Currently the list of page uids is hardcoded. That could be made configureable via extension manager settings.
- A check could be implemented to only delete the cache if the file has a certain sys_category assigned, e.g. Downloads

But for the moment this solution is enough for my needs.